# Late 90s or early 2k movie; woman discovers an alien who disguises itself as human; she is captured to be sacrificed

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I started watching where a cute women was wandering around a desert when she finds a man, far away, who is half silver humanoid kinda thing... It disguises itself with a human body while she's approaching from behind at a distance, and when she comes closer to it, it has transformed to a full human disguise. The last thing I remember, she was captured by some kind of a Egyptian civilization, tribe, or colony (Not the 1994 *Stargate* movie) and they strip her naked for some sacrificial act (Yes there was an uncensored nude scene presented).

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to find some more questions you can answer to improve your question.